# Wrapping shared variables using Rebol 3 FFI

Tags: rebol, rebol3

Atronix Rebol 3 FFI looks pretty good in wrapping external functions, but I cannot find any references about wrapping external variables using it.

For example, Curses/NCurses library have the external variable stdscr defined in C as

```
extern WINDOW *stdscr;
```

I want to use it in my Rebol code. Ideally I want to use it as a common Rebol variable, but a read-only access (as a result of a function call, for example) would be great too.

Is it possible with Rebol 3 FFI?

I know that this practice might be considered harmful, but sometimes external libraries are written this way.

Comment: In my humble case I've just wrapped **stdscr** as it is done in Red/System curses binding, but the problem is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [commit](https://github.com/zsx/r3/commit/0418a79b96adb5aa5eeee7741d7e4c89ea1bbd4f). Prebuild binaries can be downloaded from [here](http://www.atronixengineering.com/downloads) (only in development releases)

Here is the example code:

```
rebol []

ncurses: make library! %libncursesw.so

stdscr: make struct! compose/deep [
    [
        extern: [(ncurses) "stdscr"]
    ]
    ptr [pointer]
]

print ["stdscr:" stdscr/ptr]
close ncurses
```